# Limit of the expression

Tags: calculus, probability, sequences-and-series, limits

I want to find following limit 
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}|\ln n-\ln k|\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^k=?$$
To use computer programs is also allowed. Thanks for your helps...

Comment: You have a problem here: The $k=0$ term in the sum, for any fixed $n$, is infinite (or undefined) because of the $\ln k$.  Are you sure the sum should not start at $k=1$?

Comment: I dont know about distribution but when $p=1/n$ is it the expected value of $|\ln x-\ln n|$ in geometric distribution.

Comment: Since a variable with the geometric distribution has a finite probability of being zero, the expected value of that difference of logs is undefined.

Comment: You are right we should take  k's  from 1.

Comment: you are right, I edited the question as $k=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a [geometric distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) with parameter $p$ we have:
$$\mathbb{P}[X=k]=p(1-p)^{k-1}$$
for $k=1,2,3,\ldots$. If the parameter is $p=\frac{1}{n}$ and $n\to +\infty$ the limit distribution is an [exponential distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution), so we have:
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}|\ln n-\ln k\,|\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^k=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\left|\log\frac{k}{n}\right|e^{-k/n},\tag{1}$$
but the last sum is a [Riemann sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum), converging to:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\left|\log x\right|e^{-x}\,dx = \gamma-2\,\text{Ei}(-1) = \color{red}{1.0159835336925734\ldots},\tag{2}$$ 
where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) and $\text{Ei}$ is the [exponential integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral).

Such a limit has the following fast-converging series representation:
$$ -\gamma-2\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k\cdot k!}.\tag{3}$$

Comment: İs the integral form 0 to 1?

Comment: @guest: no, it is from $0$ to $+\infty$. $k$ is not bounded in the range $[1,n]$.

Comment: thanks for your help, I will focus on the solution for few days to grasp it. Is there a problem if ı ask you more both about this solution and about distribution theory ?

Comment: @guest: no problem, just follow the links to get a sketch of the techniques involved, then I will answer to your doubts.

Comment: Indepent from this question, I have another related question.Let $(a_n)$ be real valued sequence. Then, under which conditions on $a_n$ ,we can write $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k\left(1- \frac{1}{n}\right)^k=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}a_ke^{-k/n}$?

Comment: @guest: we just need $a_k\geq 0$ and that the first limit exists to be able to apply convergence in distribution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23726/discussion-between-guest-and-jack-daurizio).

Answer (score 1):

To get to the improper integral directly: We have

$$S_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|\ln (k/n)|[(1-1/n)^n]^{k/n}.$$

Now $(1-1/n)^n$ increases to $1/e$ as $n$ increases to $\infty.$ Let $0<a<1/e.$ Then for large $n$ we have

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|\ln (k/n)|a^{k/n} \le S_n \le \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|\ln (k/n)|e^{-k/n}.$$

Let $n\to \infty$ to get

$$\int_0^\infty |\ln x|a^{x}\,dx \le \liminf S_n \le \limsup S_n \le \int_0^\infty |\ln x|e^{-x}\,dx.$$

This is true for any $0<a<1/e.$ Now let $a$ increase to $1/e$ and use the dominated convergence theorem to see the desired limit of $S_n$ is the integral on the right above.